# PyMongo NoneType error when I try to use None as null for query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi guys and sorry for my bad english. I am using pymongo for querying to mongodb. so when i try to use None as null in my query, I get error: NoneType object is not subscriptable.

Here is an example:

```
db.collection.find_one({'name': "Nick", 'age': None})
# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error
```

Can you help me to solve this problem, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying for null field using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515590/querying-for-null-field-using-pymongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, not tried but try passing `null` instead of `None`:

```
db.collection.find_one({'name': "Nick", 'age': null})
```

Comment: can you try `find` method instead of `find_one` ?

Comment: Although it should have worked earlier with `None`. Also, it is advised to use `None` with the PyMongo Python driver to query for null or missing fields in MongoDB in their docs  - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked, or post the correct answer.